# Multisite for intranet/extranet

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I'm currently developing a Drupal environment for a school project. I've already read a few books about Drupal, but still need to improve my skills when it comes to programming.

The project exists of developing a new intranet/extranet for existing content. Currently, the intranet/extranet exists of standard html files linked to eachother. The content on the intranet(intranet.example.com) is only available for users on the company network. However, some content needs to be available on the extranet (extranet.example.com).

I'd like to use one Drupal installation to manage all content, users... Is this possible by using a multisite configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-site is designed for a shared codebase with seperated content.
It is possible to share a few tables within all multi-sites without complications (e.g. users, roles, session) but espacially sharing  of content and content-types is not quite easy.

I would suggest **Domain Access**: http://drupal.org/project/domain

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database. The module allows you to share users, content, and configurations across a group of sites

Comment: Thank you both (@sly) for your response. I'll be looking into both solutions, but knowing multi-site isn't a proper solution already helps me out alot. I'll post my results later.

Comment: Domain Access seems to be the best solution for this particular project. Thanks you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you really well:

[Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og)

Documentation is great and you can find many videos on youtube explaining how to work with this module (I'm using it myself for exactly the same purpose)

I wouldn't use multisite for that as per

> However, some content needs to be available on the extranet...

Comment: Are you using OG 7.x-1.x or 7.x-2.x? I'm still figuring out the main differences between the two.

Comment: Im on 7.x-2.x. Looking at 1.x it does not look like its being "actively" maintained - last update Sep 2012. I would recommend using 2.x

Comment: I'm not seeing how you could use organic groups to easily make a domain intranet.example.com and a domain extranet.example.com. I've gone through the documentation and some YouTube videos, but it just seems too basic to me. Did you write custom modules yourself?